# CSS thead gradient-background on mobile issue

Tags: html, css, html-table, gradient

I have a gradient in my table css. On desktop browsers like Chrome, Firefox and Safari it looks as intended, however on mobile browsers it does not have the intended effect. Gradient is supposed to stretch on the entire header but on mobile it repeats on header cells instead.

Anyone able to help me?

[This is how it looks on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUmMi.png)

[This is how it looks on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiPpY.png)

This is the css that I implementen. Should be fine but I cannot figure out why it doesn't work on mobile.

```css
table thead {
  background:  linear-gradient(to right, #ffcf28, #f28d00);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #ffcf28, #f28d00);
}
table th:first-child {
 border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}
table th:last-child {
 border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
table th {
  color: white;
 background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Kostensoort</th>
      <th>Tarief</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
/* cut the cells for clarity */
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would try to use `table thead tr {...}` as a selector for the gradient background

Comment: Does it look like that on mobile on both Firefox and Chrome? Why do you have the background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient line? Is that just for Safari?

Comment: Thanks for replying Johannes, I have tested that and it makes no difference. On mobile it still applies gradients to th cells separately.

Comment: Hi dgrogan, gradient looks like that on Safari and Chrome mobile. The -webkit-linear-gradient is for Safari clients.

Comment: Funny thing I just noticed: on mobile the gradient is to left instead of to right. That is puzzling.